# How do I disable JMeter reporting in non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, jmeter-maven-plugin

Is there a way to completly disable Jmeter reporting in non-gui mode?
so it does not create any html reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is disabled by default so nothing to do.

It is enabled by :

> -e -o outputfolder
>
> -g csvfile - o outputfolder

From your comment, you may be adding one of the options above which trigger report generation.

It seems you're using [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/), in this case, use version 2.8.6 and set as per [wiki](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Test-Results-File-Format#4):

```
 <configuration>
    <resultsFileFormat>xml</resultsFileFormat>
    <generateReports>false</generateReports>
 </configuration>
```

This [tutorial](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/) can help you using this maven plugin.

Comment: But when I running it, I get:

2019-02-20 16:06:45,209 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property

Comment: I am using the maven jmeter plugin. Just calling jmeter in the integration-test phase.
I also have the property set: jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
This is an old Jmeter test (before Jmeter 3 and its report system) I am convertir to Jmeter 5.
I already had all the script to use the jmeter xsl transform to generate an html report and capture it in Jenkins, and i would like to keep this way as it works well for us as is.

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml in this case ? Which version of jmeter-maven-plugin are you using ?

Comment: I am using 2.8.0 but I did not know about this property.
Now it works. ty

Comment: you're welcome, happy to help. If you can also upvote. Thanks